# i do not want bullets in the html:errors while using struts validation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, validation

So is there any possible way to remove bullets from the validation errors.

```
   public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
            String method = request.getParameter("method");
            ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
            if (method != null) {
                if (method.equals("changepwd")) {
                    if (this.password == null || this.password.length() < 1) {
                        errors.add("password", new ![enter image description here][1]ActionMessage("errors.required","Password"));
                        //TODO: add 'error.name.required' key to your resources
                    } 
                   if (this.cnfpassword == null || this.cnfpassword.length() < 1) {
                        errors.add("cnfpassword", new ActionMessage("errors.required","Confirm Password"));
                        //TODO: add 'error.name.required' key to your resources
                    }
                }
            }
            return errors;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following message keys, shown here with their defaults (I think; I don't recall):

```
errors.header=<h3><font color="red">Validation Errors</font></h3><ul>
errors.footer=</ul>
errors.prefix=<li>
errors.suffix=</li>
```

[Here's some further info.](http://www.niallp.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/HelpTagsErrorsAndMessages.html#example1)

Comment: thanks for your concern... But i dont get where i use this :(

Comment: @Maninder That's why I provided the link. You put the keys in your message/resource file. The alternative is displaying them manually.

Comment: Thanx a alot the problem is solved now i have changed <li> tag to <td> tag and it satisfied me what i was wanted :)